# What is the cup of coffee meaning in "cutie pie"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-play

I've stumbled upon this image of a narrow angle, coffee cup and the mathematical symbol of pi.

[image]

I get its reference to *acute* and *pie*, meaning *a cutie pie*.

But what on Earth is the coffee cup supposed to bring to the table?

Comment: The **e** of "acut*e*" is silent. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/acute

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In one of the comments from the link provided, you'd see, "acute tea pie". So, it isn't necessarily a cup of coffee. A cup of tea, it is. Hence, 'A cutie pie'.

Comment: Perhaps I'm slow today but I still can't see how the cup of any beverage contributes here. If omitted, I still get *a cutie pie* when pronouncing. Am I mistaken on how to pronounce, perhaps mislead by already knowing the correct answer?

Comment: Maybe you have to be English to understand tea?

Comment: 'A cute' doesn't sound the same as 'a cutie', hence, **tea** is added. "Tea" is for the /ee/ sound.

Comment: @KonradV - Without the beverage, this rebus would say: _You are a cute pie_ – which is **not** what the person is trying to say!

Comment: Yes, you're apparently mispronouncing *acute*. It's pronounced like "a cute" not like "a cutie".